# SharePoint Online Highlighted Content Query Text Grouping

Tags: sharepoint-online, query, file, kql, highlighted-content-web-part

Using the SharePoint Online Highlighted Content web part, is there a way to group the files using the query text and KQL?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. You could use sort by in the highlighted content web part.

[image]